# GD в PHP подписывается

Tags: php, gd

Привет всем!
Вопрос про библиотеку GD в PHP.

Как сделать, чтобы GD не подписывал JPEG. Или как можно убрать эту подпись? Примерно в начале файла он добавляет такую запись:

```
CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 88
```

Comment: Используйте Imagick для создания картинок/превьюшек.

Comment: Выложите пример кода.